# Android client is not working with server pc

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am trying to a develop a basic app for sending a string from an android client to pc server but problem is that the server is not receiving any message.I am using socket to communicate between client and server.The server is started but doesnt receving any message.
    Here is the sample server code written in java

```
     /*
         * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
         * and open the template in the editor.
         */
        package wifi.communicate;
        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.net.InetAddress;
        import java.net.ServerSocket;
        import java.net.Socket;
         public class WIfiCommunicate 
        {

            private static final int port=4444;
            private static ServerSocket serversocket;
            private static Socket clientsocket;
            private static InputStreamReader reader;
            private static BufferedReader breader;
            private static InputStreamReader InputStreamReader;
            private static String message;

            public static void main(String[] args) 
            {
               try
               {
                serversocket=new ServerSocket(port,0,InetAddress.getLocalHost());
                System.out.println("IP:  "+serversocket.getInetAddress()+  "port" +serversocket.getLocalPort()); 

               }
               catch(IOException e)
               {
                   System.out.println("Could not listen to port: "+port);
               }
               System.out.println("Server started ");
               while(true)
               {
                   try
                   {
                   clientsocket=serversocket.accept();
                   reader=new InputStreamReader(clientsocket.getInputStream());  
                   breader=new BufferedReader(reader);
                   message=breader.readLine();

                   }
                   catch(IOException e)
                   {
                       System.out.println("Message not received");
                   }
               }
            }   
        }

here is the android activity code

        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.PrintWriter;
        import java.net.Socket;
        import java.net.UnknownHostException;
       import android.os.AsyncTask;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.EditText;

        public class MainActivity extends Activity {

            EditText editText;
            String n1;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);


            }
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                if(view.getId()==R.id.button1)
                {
                    n1=editText.getText().toString();
                    new connectserver().execute(n1);
                }
            }   
            public class connectserver extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Socket> 
            {
                private static final String IP_address="192.168.0.101";
                private static final int port=4444;
                private String mText;
                protected Socket doInBackground(String... params)
                {
                    if(params.length!=1)
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException();


                    mText=params[0];

                    Socket client=null;
                    try
                    {
                        client=new Socket(IP_address,port);
                    }
                    catch(UnknownHostException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                    catch(IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return client;
                }
                protected void onPostExecute(Socket client)
                {
                    try
                    {
                       PrintWriter pwriter;
                       String message=mText;

                       editText.setText("");

                       pwriter=new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
                       pwriter.write(message);

                       pwriter.flush();
                       pwriter.close();
                       client.close();

                    }
                    catch(IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
            {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;
            }

        }
```